# Redirect all pages to the index page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a temporary static HTML page. But there are a bunch of URL's added to an other website. All these URL's go to page a that doesn't exist at the moment. So it needs to be redirected to the index page.

So every page needs to be redirected to https://experienceantwerp.be

Example page that doesn't exist at the moment: https://experienceantwerp.be/nl/aanbod/gidsenwandelingen/geschiedenis/voetgangerstunnel

When you go to that URL, the styles are gone.

My current .htaccess file is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html/$1 [L]
```

When I try this, for example: https://experienceantwerp.be/hfhfhf it seems to work. I guess if there is one slash in the URL, it works.

**Update**: I've found a solution, but it doesn't feel right. When I add the CSS and JS file with there absolute path, it works.

Comment: Will these other pages exist at some point? What you've implemented above is an "internal rewrite", not a redirect. You are serving the static HTML page at every (incorrect) URL - essentially creating duplicate content (unless you are taking additional steps to resolve this)?

Comment: "Update: I've found a solution" - is this different to the "solution" you've shown above?

Comment: These pages will exist in the near future and when they do, the static page will be removed. The issue was that my JS and CSS files weren't correctly linked if you go to a url like this domain.com/en/this-is-a-test/. Problably because it looks for the CSS file on this path domain.com/en/css/style.css and not on the correct path domain.com/css/style.css 

So my solution was to link the CSS, ... with its absolute path and not relatively.

Comment: Yes, using relative URL paths to your static resources would be a problem here and correcting these to either root-relative (starting with a slash) or even absolute is the solution (as you have done). See also [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Comment: Although, if you simply want your temporary static page to display, you probably don't need to pass the URL-path as path-info on `index.html` (that is likely to trigger a 404 on most servers). Also look at `FallbackResource`.